# Perl Variable References in Hash / Foreach

Tags: perl, reference

I would like to change variables stored in a hash, but I kept receiving the error:

`"Can't use the string ("SCALAR(0x30f558)") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at - line 14.`

My simplified code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $num = 1234;
my $a = 5;

my %hash = (\$num => "value");

foreach my $key (keys %{hash}){
    print "Key: $key\n";
    #OPTION1: $a = $$key;
}

my $ref = \$num ;
print "Ref: $ref\n";
#OPTION2: $a = $$ref ;

print $a;
```

Running this prints:

```
Key: SCALAR(0x30f558)
Ref: SCALAR(0x30f558)
5
```

showing that both $key and $ref are pointing to the same variable - $num

Also, the code on OPTION1 and OPTION2 are identical if $key and $ref are the same.

When I uncomment OPTION2, $a prints out as 1234.

When I uncomment OPTION1, however, I receive the error shown above.

QUESTION:
How do I change $a to $num using the hash as I tried to do in OPTION1? And why will this not work as is?

---

References:
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHIPS/perl5.004_05/t/pragma/strict-refs

I followed this code closely:

```
use strict 'refs' ;
my $fred ;
my $b = \$fred ;
my $a = $$b ;
```

which posed no error until I introduced the hash.

Thank you for your help.

---

Original Code (doesn't work):

```
#User Defined - here are the defaults
my $a = 122160;
my $b = 122351;
my $c = 'string';
my $d = 15;
my $e = 123528;
#etc.

#Create variable/print statement hash
my %UserVariables = (
\$a =>  "A: (Default: $a): ",
\$b =>  "B: (Default: $b): ",
\$c =>  "C: (Default: $c): ",
\$d =>  "D: (Default: $d): ",
\$e =>  "E: (Default: $e): ",
);

#Allow user to change variables if desired
foreach (keys %UserVariables){
    print $UserVariables{$_};
    chomp (my $temp = <>);
    print "$_\n";
    $$_ = $temp unless ($temp eq '');
    print "$temp\n" unless ($temp eq '');
};
```

Less efficient method that does work:

```
#Alternate Method without loops (not ideal)
my $temp;
print $UserVariables{\$a};
    chomp ($temp = (<>));
    $a= $temp unless ($temp eq '');
print $UserVariables{\$b};
    chomp ($temp = (<>));
    $b= $temp unless ($temp eq '');
print $UserVariables{\$c};
    chomp ($temp = (<>));
    $c= $temp unless ($temp eq '');
print $UserVariables{\$d};
    chomp ($temp = (<>));
    $d= $temp unless ($temp eq '');
print $UserVariables{\$e};
    chomp ($temp = (<>));
    $e= $temp unless ($temp eq '');
```

Comment: The code shows that `$key` and `$ref` share the same string representation.  One of them *is* a string, and the other is a scalar reference that is stringified for printing.

Comment: Before you try dereferencing the $key and $ref variables print out ref( $key ) and ref( $ref ) and you'll see that only the $ref variable is an actual reference like pilcrow said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl hash keys can only be string. You don't have reference as key, but what your reference automatically stringified to: a verbatim string "SCALAR(0x30f558)" instead. Obviously, string won't work as reference.

You should rethink the way you store data and maybe explain in little more details **what** you want to do instead on focusing on **how**.

In your particular case illustrated by example just use plain hash for those values you want to be overridable:

```
my %config = (
   a => 122160,
   b => 122351,
   c => 'string',
   d => 15,
   e => 123528,
);
```

...and then overwrite values in this hash.

Comment: Got it, thanks. In my program, I have a lot of variables that I want defined through <STDIN>, so I thought it would be better to loop than copy/paste the input and variable names over and over. That's why I turned to a hash, but I understand why it won't work in that way.
Is there a way to pass actual variables through a loop and change each of them in turn? That's my final goal, but I wanted to understand why this didn't work also.

Comment: @smileham, why not just use a plain hash? See updated answer.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov add for your post INFO about `=>` for better understanding of hash initialization. good answer, however! well done!

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov That's definitely a good idea, and after I finished my entire program (referencing variables $a, etc. instead of $variables{a}) I realized that, so I was trying to fix it after-the-fact. I think I'll just replace all of $a with $variables{a} because that really does make more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to change variables stored in a hash

Just like you can't store variables in a scalar, you can't store variables in hashes. You can store values (including references to variables) in hashes. (Such as the string `value` in your code.)

> showing that both $key and $ref are pointing to the same variable - $num

No. It shows that the values of `$key` and `$ref` have the same stringification.

> When I uncomment OPTION1, however, I receive the error shown above.

Hash table keys are necessarily strings, just like array keys are necessarily non-negative integers.

> I followed this code closely:

No, the same with hashes works fine.

```
use strict 'refs' ;
my %hash = ( fred => undef );
my $b = \$hash{fred} ;
my $a = $$b ;
```

I can't provide a solution, because you didn't say what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but is there a way to pass actual variables through a loop and change each of them in turn (through <STDIN>)?

Comment: In my program, I have a lot of variables that I want defined through <STDIN>, so I thought it would be better to loop than copy/paste the input and variable names over and over. That's why I turned to a hash.

My original code for the loop looks like this:

`foreach (keys %UserVariables){
        print $UserVariables{$_};
        chomp (my $temp = <>);
        print "$_\n";
        $$_ = $temp unless ($temp eq '');
        print "$temp\n" unless ($temp eq '');
    };`

so that the user could change them if desired. Does that make sense?

Comment: @smileham, No, not really. I can't even tell what are you reading from ARGV. Use words. Say what you want to do, not how.

Answer (score 0):

You keep saying in the comments that you want to modify variables passed through STDIN, however it is not clear what you mean by this.  Are you passing command line arguments or requesting input from the user or piping the output of another program into yours, or something else entirely?  The ideal approach will vary slightly depending on what you're trying to do.

To read command line arguments you access the `@ARGV` array:

```
$foo = $ARGV[0]; #read the first argument
```

To read a line off of STDIN:

```
print "Enter a number: ";
$foo = <STDIN>;
```